# How to verify a disabled button using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, disabled-control

HTML of the button:

```html
<button class="Button1" disabled type="button" xpath="1">submit Button</button>
```

```
def isButtonDisabled(self):
    element = self.element.findElement(By.xpath, 'locator')
    return element.get_property('disabled')
```

But this method is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in WebDriver called `is_enabled` which returns true if the element is enabled, else it returns false.

```
def isButtonDisabled(self):
    element = self.element.findElement(By.xpath, 'locator')
    return element.is_enabled()
```

Here's a [Reference](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled) in the documentation of selenium py

Answer (score 0):

`"disabled"` is not a *property*, but *attribute* so you need to replace

```
element.get_property('disabled')
```

with

```
element.get_attribute('disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

### [disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp) Attribute

The *`disabled`* attribute is a boolean attribute which specifies that the element should be ***disabled*** unless some prerequisites are met. A *`disabled`* element is unusable. Generally the *`disabled`* attribute can be set to keep a user from using the element until some other condition has been met e.g. selecting a checkbox, radio button, etc.

---

### This usecase

As per the given HTML:

```
<button class="Button1" disabled type="button" xpath="1">submit Button</button>
```

To probe if the `<button>` is ***disabled*** you can perform the following test:

```
try:
    self.element.findElement(By.xpath, '//button[text()="submit Button"][disabled]')
    print("button is disabled")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("button wasn't disabled")
```